# Не работает JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

1. Выполняю вот [эту инструкцию](http://devcolibri.com/1250)
2. Запускаю проект, падает ошибка:

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in
>   method that is not native or abstract in class file
>   javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/ConditionalTagSupport

У меня java 1.8, tomcat 8.0.28, maven 3.3.3.

Что я делаю не так?
Вот сам [проект](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx4t8kgPM32zeTFGdi1IZHBEUEE&usp=sharing)

Comment: Может потому, что проект совершенно пустой? `MyFirstWebProject Пустая папка`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Вероятно не хватает какой-то библиотеки. Например есть библиотека API, но она не содержит кода. Нужна библиотека реализации. Кое-кто утверждает, что tomcat поставляется без jstl, Надо самостоятельно найти это дело. Вам нужна зависимость jstl-impl. http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/ Это касается tomcat 7, но может и в 8 такая же ситуация